# tfjs mode.predict returns same reults

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a web model running on the browser. which does face detection the problem is that randomly the predict starts to return all gibberish results or the same result everytime.

I have observed sometimes its the `tf.browser.fromPixels` seem to return a all zero tensor. I have checked the `frame` and it seems to be valid.

any idea on what could be happening.

```
      const pixels = tf.browser.fromPixels(frame).toFloat();
  const shape = pixels.reshape([-1, 104, 104, 3]);

  const tfResponse: any = this.model.predict(shape);
  tfResponse.data().then((r) => {

    try {

      if ( this.lastResponse ) {
        if ( UtilService.arraysEqual(r, this.lastResponse )) {
          throw new Error('Prediction failure start');
        }
      }
      this.lastResponse = r;
      shape.dispose();

      const detections: Array<Box> = this.parseDetectionResult(r);

      if (detections.length > 0) {

        resolve({resized: frame, face: detections});

      } else {

        reject('No face found.');

      }

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }


  })
```

HTML

```html
<app-camera-overlay _ngcontent-c8="" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%" _nghost-c11="">
  <canvas _ngcontent-c11="" class="abs-center" id="mask-overlay" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
</app-camera-overlay>
```

usually its the `pixels` the seem to be filled with zero's.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the HTML code where you have the image or canvas element ?

Comment: @edkeveked added the HTML.

Comment: If `frame` holds the `canvas` element of your html code and that the canvas is not empty, then your code should work. From the snippet you showed, the canvas does not contain any value, so the tensor would be empty. Maybe the error lies in the way you are filling your canvas or the way you are querying it. Could you please add the code relative to how you are getting the frame data or filling your canvas with image ? Also you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079831/tf-browser-frompixels-returns-only-zeros/55082918#55082918